# DynamoDb put does not write/save to table in lambda test or cron but works in Serverless

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am scraping a bunch of API's and saving the data to a dynamodb table.

Everything works absolutely fine when running `serverless invoke local -f runAggregator` locally.

However, after I set up the cron, I noticed things were not being saved to the Dynamodb table.

Here is my function:

```js
module.exports.runAggregator = async (event) => {
  await runModules({ saveJobs: true });

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Aggregate",
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
};
```

And the `runModules` function:

```js
module.exports = async ({ saveJobs }) => {
  if (saveJobs) {
    const flushDb = await flushDynamoDbTable();
    console.log("Flushing Database: Complete");
    console.log(flushDb);
  }

  // pseudo code
  const allJobs = myLongArrayOfJobsFromApis

  const goodJobs = allJobs.filter((job) => {
    if (job.category) {
      if (!job.category.includes("Missing map for")) return job;
    }
  });

  // This runs absolutely fine locally...
  if (saveJobs) goodJobs.forEach(saveJob); // see below for function

  const badJobs = allJobs.filter((job) => {
    if (!job.category) return job; // no role found from API
    if (job.category.includes("Missing map for")) return job;
  });

  console.log("Total Jobs", allJobs.length);
  console.log("Good Jobs", goodJobs.length);
  console.log("Malformed Jobs", badJobs.length);

  return uniqBy(badJobs, "category");
};
```

saveJob function

```js
// saveJob.js
module.exports = (job) => {
  validateJob(job);

  dynamoDb
    .put({
      TableName: tableName,
      Item: job,
    })
    .promise();
};
```

I am baffled as to why this works fine locally not when I run a 'test' in the lambda console. I only found out due to the table being empty after the cron had ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveJob` performs an async operation (`ddb.put().promise()`) but you are neither awaiting its completion nor returning the promise.

As the forEach in the `runModules` function will also not await anything, the function completes before the call to dynamodb is even performed (because of how promises vs synchronous code work) and the process is killed after the lambda's execution.

Locally you are not running lambda but something that looks like it. There are subtle differences, and what happens after the function is done is one of those differences. So it may work locally, but it won't on an actual lambda.

What you need to do is to make sure you await your call to dynamodb. Something like:

```js
// saveJob.js
module.exports = (job) => {
  validateJob(job);

  return dynamoDb
    .put({
      TableName: tableName,
      Item: job,
    })
    .promise();
};
```

and in your main function:

```
...
if (saveJobs) await Promise.all(...goodJobs.map(job => saveJob(job)))

// or with a Promise lib such as bluebird:
if (saveJobs) await Promise.map(goodJobs, job => saveJob(job))
// (or Promise.each(...) if you need to make sure this happens in sequence and not in parallel)
```

Note: instead of calling many times dynamodb.put, you could/should call once (or at least fewer times) the [batchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property) operation, which can write up to 25 items in one call, saving quite a bit of latency in the process.